# Google Action Basic Card Responses Locking Up On Google Nest Hub

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a Google Action that returns a basic card as part of a response - e.g.

```
  "basicCard": {
    "title": "A bunch of text for the title of this lengthx.",
    "formattedText": "*A bunch of formatted text of the following length xxxx xx xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx.",
    "image": {
      "imageUri": "https://domainname.com/imageurl.png",
      "accessibilityText": "Card Image"
    }
```

The card is returned on each call.

Just recently on a Google Nest Hub, I started seeing the following behavior:

1. We launch the action via “talk to [actionname]” which then asks a "Yes/No" question
2. After the user says “Yes” when the next response is delivered, it starts to display the associated card (same as the one in the first response) and the following happens:

As the card scrolls into place, the screen locks up
The device sits for about 10 seconds and then starts reading the response (on the server, we’re returning responses in the 150ms range)
It then shows the suggestion chips, but takes in no voice input and eventually shuts down

The action runs without issue on screenless devices, the test harness and on a phone so the issue looks localized to the device.

Has anyone seen anything similar? We have other actions where the cards vary text and images and those are not having any issues. As I said before, this was working fine a few weeks ago.

Thanks,
Sanj

Comment: Is it happening with any image or just the ones you have?

Answer (score -1):

Get Dialogflow agent fulfillment library (NodeJS) by using the following command:

```
yarn add dialogflow-fulfillment
OR
npm i --save dialogflow-fulfillment
```

Then require it in your project and add image using a URL:

```
const { WebhookClient, Image } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment')
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response })
agent.add(
  new Image('https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/36980416')
)
```

Comment: Hi Delon, welcome to stackoverflow. Thank you for your answer, sadly I had to downvote it since the OP stated that the cards are working fine on phone devices, so it very unlikely that a swap of library is the proper answer. Besides this the Dialogflow library and the code you use will create the same type of card response, so it probably wont change anything. Feel free to edit your answer if you have more information, if you need more help with answering have a look at the help section. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Delon, thanks for the suggestion - the url in the example above was just an example - the real card uses a real image - just not including it to protect my client's confidentiality. Since this was all working until *just* recently, I'm suspecting a recent firmware update to Google Nest Hub may be the culprit. https://9to5google.com/2020/05/15/nest-hub-1-46-update/